# What would be the temperature of a thermal photon distribution with the same energy density as the current baryonic energy density?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, cosmology, spectroscopy

what would be the temperature of a thermal photon distribution with the same energy density as the current baryonic energy density?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting the question as follows: what would be the temperature of a thermal photon distribution with the same energy density as the current baryonic energy density?

(Also including the neutrons, doesn't make that much difference - most of the baryons are protons anyway)

I'll also include code snippets with the python package [astropy.cosmology](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/cosmology/index.html) if you want to play around!

We need to specify the cosmological data we're going to use, I'm picking the Planck 2018 data:

```
from astropy.cosmology import Planck18 as cosmo
```

Then, we can compute the current baryonic energy density as:

```
>>> baryon_density = cosmo.Ob0 * cosmo.critical_density0
>>> print(baryon_density)
4.210839341468231e-31 g / cm3
```

and the current CMB (photon) energy density as:

```
>>> photon_density = cosmo.Ogamma0 * cosmo.critical_density0
>>> print(photon_density)
4.645092477572654e-34 g / cm3
```

You can see that there are roughly 3 orders of magnitude between them.
Also, note that here they are already reported as mass densities, implicitly using the equation you mention; multiply by $c^2$ to get the current energy densities in electronvolts per cubic centimeter, for example

```
>>> import astropy.constants as ac
>>> import astropy.units as u
>>> print((photon_density*ac.c**2).to(u.eV / u.cm**3))
0.26057057825809343 eV / cm3
```

Now, the CMB's temperature is roughly 2.7 degrees Kelvin. How much does it increase if we raise the energy density by a factor ~1000?

It is known that the energy density of a distribution scales with the fourth power of its temperature, $\rho = \sigma_{SB} T^4$, where $\sigma_{SB}$ is the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant).

This means that we can compute the equivalent temperature you ask for by solving:
$$ \rho_{\text{baryons}} = \sigma_{SB} T^4
$$
which we could do manually, but since we know that $\rho_{\text{CMB}} = \sigma_{SB} T^4_{\text{CMB}}$ we can divide the equations through to get:
$$ \frac{\rho_{\text{baryons}}}{\rho_{\text{CMB}}} = \left( \frac{T}{T_{\text{CMB}}}\right)^4
$$

So,

```
>>> T = (baryon_density / photon_density)**(1/4) * cosmo.Tcmb0
>>> print(T)
<Quantity 14.95511521 K>
```

Not that much warmer!

Comment: The reason I asked was because if Fred Hoyles idea of continuous matter creation had been right then presumably the energy to create baryons had come from 
space or a vacuum or  somewhere and I was wondering if it could have contributed to the CMB or dark energy for example in the past.I am aware that most cosmologists don't agree with Hoyle. I personally do agree with him though.